# Command Prompt not responding after running django server

Tags: python, django

Windows command prompt gets stuck after i run my django server
seems working, and the server works in the browser but i cant type any thing in the command prompt

[image: Screen Shot]

any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: If you press Ctrl+Break when in command line window, doesn't stop the dev server?

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? This sounds like an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Nothing unusual, webserver is running as console application, it's not a windows server as you may expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's exactly what's expected - the dev server is not meant to run as a service, it's only here for local development purpose. Use another command prompt if you have other things to do while the dev server is running.

Comment: Thank you, that has solved my problem

Comment: @MJerjawi glad I could help - and feel free to accept the answer then ;)